# How to do data or model parallel training?

Tags: .net, deep-learning, pytorch, multi-gpu

I see a few examples of data and model parallel training with PyTorch. It doesn't seem supported by TorchSharp out of the box, correct me if I'm wrong. Even if that is not supported out of the box, do you have examples how to do it making data transfers between GPUs explicitly? I mean data parallelism boils down to training on N GPUs with identical copies of the model. There is a step in the training where we need to combine gradients from all the models, right? I don't quite understand how and when to do that. A step-by-step list of actions with examples of what calls to the APIs should be made would help. My model size is about 400K parameters, and I have about 1.5x10^9 training samples. It takes about 5 days to go through one round of feeding all samples on my system, but I have 2 GPUs and 1 powerful CPU so, I would like to try to use all the resources in a hope to reduce the training time at least twice.

**UPDATE**

Let me rephrase the question. I hope it'll make it clearer. I use TorchSharp which as well as PyTorch is a wrapper on top of C/C++ libtorch. In TorchSharp I don't have ready to be used libraries to do parallel training of any kind. Thus, I need to understand how to do it with the basic functionality of libtorch/PyTorch/TorchSharp. Basically, I can do all tensor operations in a similar way to how PyTorch can do it.

Now, if let's say I load my model into GPU0 and GPU1, then run one batch on GPU0 and another batch on GPU1. How do I synchronize the gradients in GPU0 and GPU1 after that with just the basic abilities of libtorch/PyTorch/TorchSharp? Any example in any language would work. If somebody knows how to do it in PyTorch, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about how you could train your model on your GPU to decrease model training time. To do so, you need to configure your GPU than make sure that they are not busy than train your model. It is essential that your GPU are not busy at the moment when you start training your model.

- For more details refer to https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/ddp_tutorial.html

Comment: The question is how to train a model using multiple GPUs with TorchSharp? There is no DistributedDataParallel in TorchSharp at least yet. PyTorch documentation does not explain what is happening when the gradients synchronization happens when DistributedDataParallel is used. I need to know how exactly that synchronization is done to repeat this process for TorchSharp with custom code.